# View is not loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

**MoviePlayerAppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    viewController = [[MoviePlayerViewController alloc] init];
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

**MoviePlayerViewController.m**

```
-(void)loadView {
    //Setup the view.
    [self setView:[[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease]];
    [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [[self view] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    //Add play button.
    playButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(53, 212, 214, 36)];
    [playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [[self view] addSubview:playButton];
}
```

But somehow `view` is not loading. I could not find mistake in code. Please help to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it in this way or not. But i didn't did it in that way. I made another UIViewController Class, and played video in that.

Comment: window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
what is the need of this ??

Comment: Is some view assigned to aMoviePlayerViewController.view? Either in code or nib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Remove the code

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

and change addSubView as below.

```
[self.window addSubview:viewController.view];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define UIView in your header file a then attache it to self.view

```
MoviePlayerViewController.h
UIView *contentView;

@property (retain, nonatomic) UIView                    *contentView;

MoviePlayerViewController.m

@synthesize contentView;

- loadView {

CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];
contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

self.view = contentView;
[contentView release];
}
```

this definitely works.